# ggplot - linetype aes does not work as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2

The linetypes in the plot are not consistent with the data

```
library(tidyverse)

segments <- tibble(x = c(1,3,5), y = c(1,1,1),
                   xend = c(2,4,6), yend = c(1,1,1),
                   ltype = c("dashed", "twodash", "solid"))
ggplot(segments, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend, linetype = ltype), size = 1.5)
```

results in:
[image]

Please advise

Comment: `+ scale_linetype_identity()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Roland pointed out, you can use `scale_*_identity()` when you have values in a column that should be used "as is" to represent the way to draw that particular aesthetic.  By default, the legend will not be drawn when you do this, so you'll have to specify that in the `scale_()` function if you want the general legend:

```
# where p represents your plot code...
p + scale_linetype_identity(guide='legend')
```

[image]

You might notice a kind of annoying thing in that legend, though.  Since the line size is large, the glyph (the icon representing the label in the legend) doesn't represent "dashed" or "twodash" exceptionally well.  You can change that by overwriting the aesthetics in the legend to draw the legend glyphs with different aesthetics applied to them.  You can also "stretch" out the width of the legend keys via access of `theme()` elements:

```
p + scale_linetype_identity(guide='legend') +
  guides(linetype=guide_legend(
    override.aes = list(size=0.8)
  )) +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(50, 'pt'))
```

[image]